# Highlighting a substring within a FILTER function array

Tags: excel, vba, filter, substring, highlight

In cell B22, I have the following formula:

```
=FILTER('List View'!$C$22:$C$1030, 'List View'!$B$22:$B$1030=B20,"")
```

The code is looking up cell B20, which equals a date, and on cells B22 to B29 it is returning whatever it finds from the sheet "list view".

My goal is to highlight specific substring, should it exist in the output. I have the below code, which works but only if the substring is hard coded or manually entered in my range B22 to B29. Is there a way to fix this? It seems the code is reading the output but when executing nothing happens.

Any help would be super helpful!!

---

```
Public Sub HighlightCodes()
     Dim Codes(1 To 8)
     Dim rng As Range
     Set rng = Range("B22:B28")
     Dim i As Long
     Dim StartPos As Long
           Codes(1) = "Erik"
           Codes(2) = "Mike"
           Codes(3) = "Name3"
           Codes(4) = "Name3"
           Codes(5) = "Name3"
           Codes(6) = "Name3"
           Codes(7) = "Name3"
           Codes(8) = "Name3"

     For Each rng In rng
           For i = 1 To 8
     StartPos = InStr(rng.Value, Codes(i))
     If StartPos > 0 Then rng.Characters(StartPos, 
Len(Codes(i))).Font.Color = vbRed
  Next i
Next rng
End Sub
```

.

```
Public Sub HighlightCodes()
     Dim Codes(1 To 8)
     Dim rng As Range
     Set rng = Range("B22:B28")
     Dim i As Long
     Dim StartPos As Long
           Codes(1) = "Erik"
           Codes(2) = "Mike"
           Codes(3) = "Name3"
           Codes(4) = "Name3"
           Codes(5) = "Name3"
           Codes(6) = "Name3"
           Codes(7) = "Name3"
           Codes(8) = "Name3"

     For Each rng In rng
           For i = 1 To 8
     StartPos = InStr(rng.Value, Codes(i))
     If StartPos > 0 Then rng.Characters(StartPos, 
Len(Codes(i))).Font.Color = vbRed
  Next i
Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data and expected results.

Comment: You want to highlight parts of a result of a formula - as far as I know this is not possible. Your code does work only for text directly written into the cell. A work-around would be to replace the results by text, but that means this will not be calculated new later and will most often not be wanted

Comment: the result from the RESULT formula can be "Company Name/Country -- Intro Meeting - Erik".

Comment: I want to be able to highlight the word "Erik"

Comment: is it not possible for the code to read the formula result? when I run the code line by line it seems to be reading the output properly and calculating the position of the substring... but when executing, the code does nothing.

Comment: You cannot highlight/color part of the cell content if the cell has a formula.  You can only do that with directly-entered content.

Comment: You can write a VBA macro which takes the results of the `FILTER` function (or executes that function itself) and then writes the results to the display range as **text strings**. You can then run `HighlightCodes`.

Comment: how would that work?